# PHP preg_match language dependent interpretation error

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, regexp-replace

Turkish characters Ş İ Ö Ü like not supported. I'm exhausted.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$test = "azAZ09andSpace supported but this turkish characters Ş İ Ö Ü like not supported";
        //So it goes to the "else block".

if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/', $test)){
echo "match";
}else{
echo "not match"; //return false. Because Ş İ Ö Ü like not supported
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't know if PHP uses PCRE or not, but it definitely doesn't use Perl. Fixed tags.

Comment: No, I just want to add Turkish characters.

Comment: `'/^[a-zA-Z0-9 {Letter}]+$/'` should it be like this?

Comment: `preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\p{L} ]+$/u', $test)` Very very very! Thank you @ikegami.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\pL` matches any letter (including accented letters), so you can use the following:

```
preg_match('/^[\pL0-9 ]+$/u', $test)
```

Similarly, `\d` matches any digit, and `\s` matches any space character, so you could also use the following:

```
preg_match('/^[\pL\d\s]+$/u', $test)
```